# Sort a PyTables table on two columns

Tags: python, sorting, pytables

I want to sort a PyTables table. Sorting on a single column is easy: I can just create a cs_index for the column I want to sort on and then use the Table.itersorted() to get the rows in sorted order, which I insert into a new table, row by row).

The problem is that I want to sort a table on *two* columns.

The table is in the following form:

```
chr   start   end    
------------------
chr1  1000    2000
chr1  1500    3000
chr2  1000    5000
chr2  1200    2000
```

In this example the order is correct, i.e. first it's sorted on 'chr', then on 'start'. Is it possible to achieve this two-column sorting in an elegant way?

P.S. I know that I can sort by extracting the columns, and then sort the numpy arrays in-memory by using numpy.lexsort, but the data I am working may sometimes be too large (possibly billions of rows)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are looking for is implemented in Pytables. So you probably have to do it yourself. My advice would be: put a csi_index on both columns and when you need to treat the data in a sorted manner, you need to implement the iteration yourself. Pull small enough bits sorted by one column into memory and then work on that (sorting with respect to the other column and treating the data).

Hope this helps